# Trigger dropzone cancel event by clicking modal outside

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I work on a project that uses the `dropzonejs` upload file component. But, I faced that issue while trying to make it more customized.

If you click **somewhere outside** of the modal window (bootstrap modal), should trigger the dropzonejs cancel button event (alert/confirm box, see the attached picture). But it does not happen like this and have never seen anything related within the documents.

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have come by this very manual and dirty way described below:

I used [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to make what I thought was real and a flag. The point is that, after the upload process successfully ends, unbind the onbeforeunlad to prevent always asking "Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?" even if it is completed.

```
var cancelConfirmation = "Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?";

var isFileInProgress = false;

var uploadZone = $("form[class=dropzone]").dropzone({
    method: "post",
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    dictCancelUploadConfirmation: cancelConfirmation,
    success: function (file, response) {
        isFileInProgress = false;

        window.onbeforeunload = function () { };
    },
    init: function () {
        this.on("error", function (file, response) {
            isFileInProgress = false;
            
            window.onbeforeunload = function () { /* unbind */ };
        });

        this.on("addedfile", function () {
            isFileInProgress = true;

            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return cancelConfirmation;
            };
        });

        this.on("complete", function () {
            isFileInProgress = false;

            window.onbeforeunload = function () { /* unbind */ };
        });

        this.on("canceled", function () {
            isFileInProgress = false;

            window.onbeforeunload = function () { /* unbind */ };
        });
    }
});

$(".modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if (isFileInProgress && !confirm(cancelConfirmation)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```